# A comma separating independent clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, commas, subordinate-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

I want to reduce the length of this sentence by adding a comma. However, Grammarly is indicating me that I should avoid it. It is not clear to me since the comma is connecting two independent but subordinate clauses. These two phrases are used in a bullet-point.

> Finding reliable sources of food in Tripoli to use in the dry season, and exploring the possible consequences on its crops because of climate change.

Comment: That's two phrases joined with a comma and the word "and", not a sentence. Why don't you show the original phrases you are trying to combine? The second phrase could be shortened by itself as "effects of climate change on Tripoli's crops", if that's what you mean.

Comment: If they are used in bullet points, why do you need to combine them? Bullet points are written on separate lines.

Comment: because they need to go together.

Comment: @Jack you are actually adding an extra word, Tripoli. It does not make it shorter.

Comment: @pepo The phrase as I put it has 7 words. Your original has 11 words. It's also clearer, since the antecedent of "its" in your original form of the second phrase is ambiguous.